# IBM Watson Visual Recognition in Java training classifier error

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

So I want to make a java application in eclipse which the user i will be able to import .zip files. Each .zip file will represent a cat breed. I will click on a "train" button and my program will contact IBM Watson services and create a classifier. Then from a different window, i will import random cat images and the program will show what cat breed is in the image. Everything with the SDKs is fine since I ran some examples from the official Watson site and everything ran smoothly. Problem comes when I try to create my own classifiers. The code you are about to see is also from their site. For some reason the `createClassifier` method won't take the `CreateClassifierOptions` object as an argument.

```
import java.io.File;

import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.http.ServiceCall;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.RecognitionCallback;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.visual_recognition.v3.*;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.visual_recognition.v3.model.*;


public class TrainningClassifier{

public static void main(String[] args) {


VisualRecognition service = new VisualRecognition(
          VisualRecognition.VERSION_DATE_2016_05_20
        );

        service.setApiKey("aca4433597018de62edafdeebceb2bdc1482496a");
        CreateClassifierOptions createClassifierOptions = new CreateClassifierOptions.Builder()
          .name("dogs")
          .addClass("beagle", new File("./beagle.zip"))
          .addClass("goldenretriever",new File("./golden-retriever.zip"))
          .addClass("husky", new File("./husky.zip"))
          .negativeExamples(new File("./cats.zip"))
          .build();

        Classifier dogs = service.createClassifier(createClassifierOptions).execute();
        System.out.println(dogs);  /*error is in the above line.
                                     the createClassifier method.*/
}

}
```

> Error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved
>   compilation problem:      The method createClassifier(ClassifierOptions)
>   in the type VisualRecognition is not applicable for the arguments
>   (CreateClassifierOptions)
>
> at testVisualRec.ForAssignment.main(ForAssignment.java:31)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. For some reason eclipse wouldn't recommend this solution I had to experiment. I just added throws `IOException` in main method. I also put inside the main method `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());` to make sure the path was correct, and it was. (SDK used for this project is 4.0.0, not the newest one. SDK found here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/releases)